# Joining two tables in SAS with SQL

Tags: sql, join, sas

I'm trying to join two tables, table1 and table2. Along with other variables, both tables have two variables, COMPANY and DATE, the combination of which uniquely identifies every observation in a given table. I want to join the two tables on COMPANY and a variable I create called DATEDIF, which is the absolute difference in the DATE variable found in table1 and the DATE variable found in table 2. If I find a match on COMPANY, I only want to keep the match if DATEDIF is less than 100. I want to keep every observation from table1, regardless of whether I find a match for it, so I am doing a left join. Here is the code I have:

```
proc sql; create table mergedtable as select
a.*, b.*, abs(a.date-b.date) as datedif
from table1 a left join table2 b
on.company=b.company
group by a.company, a.date
having datedif<100;
quit;
```

The problem is, when I do this join, mergedtable only has 2229 observations even though table1 has 2705 observations. Since I'm doing a left join on table1, I thought mergedtable should have at least 2705 observations, possibly more if more than one observation from table2 meets the matching criteria detailed above.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your HAVING is a filter that is applied after the group by.  If there is a company/date value in A which has no date value in B within 100 days, that observation is deleted due to the HAVING.  @gordon-linoff fixed that by moving it into the join criterion, so that obseveration survives due to the left join without subsequent filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
proc sql;
    create table mergedtable as
        select a.*, b.*, abs(a.date-b.date) as datedif
        from table1 a left join
             table2 b
             on.company = b.company and abs(a.date-b.date) < 100
        group by a.company, a.date;
```

Using `*` with `group by` is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I thought I needed a "group by" statement since I was using "having", but I think I was mistaken, as I've since learned that the "group by" is only needed if using a summary function. In any case, my results are the same whether I use the group by statement or not.

Comment: @user2121517 . . . You should remove the `group by`.